# Is there a JavaScript event that is triggered when a text selection is cleared?

Tags: javascript, events

I am using the JavaScript `select` event to detect when the user selects a range of characters within a textarea. However, the event does not seem to be invoked when the selection is *cleared*, either by clicking elsewhere in the textarea, or by moving the caret.

I have tested this in Chrome 12 and Firefox 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `onblur` event which you can append after a selection has being made :)

```
var t = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
t.onselect = function() {
    alert('select');
    if (typeof(t.onblur) !== 'function') {
        t.onblur = function() {
            alert('selection cleared');
            t.onblur = null;
        }
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4eG8/)

My idea: create a function which will be executed after the text has been selected, and after it's being executed unset it ... since there's no text selection any more, and when the text has been selected again - the function will be defined again

Comment: Presumably I would also need to add a onKeyPress and and an onClick event to the textarea to handle alternative methods of clearing the selection?

Comment: Yep, you need to listen for `click`, `blur`, and `keypress`. Here is a full featured [JavaScript select/unselect event listener](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/dwBrc/).

Comment: @Teneff: off topic, you need to change the spelling - you used the word witch instead of which twice :-) I hope you don't mind ... The combination is funny and funky though, witches and computing, event and function witches are a new category of witches that can manipulate events and functions.

Comment: I think change keypress to keydown as it does not catch arrow keys

Answer (score 1):

How about a combination of `click`, `blur`, and `keypress` event bound to the element?

Here is a [demo of JavaScript select/deselect event](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/dwBrc/)